# What are those comments with bracketed numbers in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to familiarise myself with Qt 5. To that end, I started looking at the provided examples. I noticed that the code is full of comments of the type //! [0], and similar numbers, sometimes several in a row.

Example: code snippet from calculator.cpp:

```
//! [1]
    display = new QLineEdit("0");
//! [1] //! [2]
    display->setReadOnly(true);
    display->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);
    display->setMaxLength(15);

    QFont font = display->font();
    font.setPointSize(font.pointSize() + 8);
    display->setFont(font);
//! [2]

//! [4]
```

I didn't find an explanation in the documentation, and the code explanation from the corresponding help file does not refer to these tags either.

Does anyone know what they are for? I mean, I know they are simply comments, but do they serve a real purpose inside Qt, like labelling of some kind?

Thanks,

Jan

Comment: it looks like that comments are some sort of bookmarks to the documentation from http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-calculator.html so like what code should be displayed where. the conetent of each `//! [n]` block matches mostly the quoted code on the site

Comment: It kind of makes sense, that's what I expected as well, but it does not match the actual code from the site/documentation. It's sort of an approximation, plus there are some missing tags, like //! [3] in the example above. I just realised, though, that it may be due to several code revisions.

Comment: yeah maybe. it is also possible that IF these are sort of bookmarks, they must not be in a row, they only need to be unique to be parsed from the webserver (it the content of the quotes gets read from the actual code files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.qtforum.org/article/32095/what-are-n-comments-for-in-qt-example-programs.html) source, they are markers for [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) documentation.